# How to use const in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, constants

I have an array that I need to use twice and I don't want to repeat it in my code

```
const menuItems = [
  { route : 'home', text : 'Game Info' },
  { route : 'players-info', text : 'Players Info' },
  { route : 'money', text : 'Money' },
  { route : 'refunds', text : 'Refounds' },
  { route : 'videos', text : 'Videos' },
  { route : 'tips', text : 'Tips' }
];
```

and in the class I am doing

```
render () {
  return <LeftNav
    menuItems={menuItems} />
}
```

so, lets say that in another file, I want to use that same `const menuItems`, and render it like this

```
  render () {

    let tabs = menuItems.map((item) => {
      return <Tab        
        key={item.route}
        label={item.text}
        route={item.route}
        onActive={this._onActive} />
    });

    return <Tabs
        initialSelectedIndex={0}>{tabs}
      </Tabs>;
  }
```

So, what should I do to use the `const` across different files?

Comment: Put it in a separate module and `import` it?

Comment: Anything you want to use outside the module has to be exported. The question doesn't really seem to have anything to do with `const` or React, but with how to organize your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// menuItems.js

```
export default const menuItems = [
  { route : 'home', text : 'Game Info' },
  { route : 'players-info', text : 'Players Info' },
  { route : 'money', text : 'Money' },
  { route : 'refunds', text : 'Refounds' },
  { route : 'videos', text : 'Videos' },
  { route : 'tips', text : 'Tips' }
];
```

// then you can import it like so

```
import menuItems from "./menuItems";
```